# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Silent Install - FullText Service Not working

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to build an installer for an app that installs SQL Server 2008 R2 ADV with fulltext already enabled, but couldn't sort it out.

It must support Windows XP, so that's the first OS I'm testing. It already has all the prerequisites installed.

The command I'm using to install is the following:

```
SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe /QUIETSIMPLE /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck 
    /ACTION=install /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=True 
    /FEATURES=SQL,BC,SSMS,FULLTEXT /INSTANCENAME=NAMED 
    /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" 
    /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" 
    /FTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" 
    /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="SomePass"
```

The result of the installation is that the service for the instance (`MSSQLFDLauncher$NAMED`) is DISABLED and the account used is `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService`, which is strange because that's not the account I passed, and the service is disabled.

Is there a way to call the installer so it just RUNS with the fulltext? If I need to change the accounts for the services (I only need `SQL` and `FULLTEXT`), that doesn't require me to create accounts, I can do so, but I really need it to work.

The documentation is poor, and I've tested all the combinations I found on the web.

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.105).aspx), the parameter /FTSVCACCOUNT is unsupported on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista operating systems. What would make you think it is supported on an older (and currently unsupported) operating system? The default value is LocalService, so this is explained. Can you add a batch file to be executed after the installer runs? That way you can enable and start the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by doing the following:

- Using the original command of the post
- Running a command to change the credential of the services (using sc.exe)
- Rebooting so the services would start (calling sc start  was not working, even if called multiple times, don't know if it's related to changing the service credentia